# Convert power shell script to C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a script in Power Shell which runs a process of Microsoft and would like to convert it to C# but did not find how to do it.

The line is as follows:

```
start-process -FilePath "telnet" -ArgumentList "-t ANSI 127.0.0.1 %Port" -Wait
```

This should run Windows Telnet.

How can I convert it to C#?

Comment: One way might be to learn C# first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick & dirty solution would be this:

```
var process = Process.Start("telnet", "-t ANSI 127.0.0.1 %Port");
process.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var p = Process.Start(@"C:\windows\sysnative\telnet.exe", "-t ANSI 127.0.0.1 %Port");
p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method. For more advanced scenarios (eg. directing standard input) you'll need to pass a [`System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) instance.

To wait for the process to exit either use the [`WaitForExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx) method (which will block) or the [`Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event.